# Separate Visual Studio Code workspace with different extensions for different programming languages

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create different Visual Studio Code workspaces separately with extensions? For example, *workspace_1* with a C++ extension and *workspace_2* with a Python extension.

Comment: Profiles might be a better option for this: "Since profiles are remembered per workspace, they are a great way to customize VS Code for a specific programming language." https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_uses-for-profiles

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can install extensions and then enable/disable them on specific workspaces.

1. Open a workspace
2. From the Extensions panel, click on the gear icon of each extension

   - If it's enabled, you can disable it on this workspace

     [image]
   - If it's disabled, you can enable it for this workspace

     [image]
3. Click on the three dots at the top-right to list either all enabled or disabled

   [image]

There is unfortunately no way to configure this from *settings.json* file (user, workspace, or folder), as the [extensions information does not seem to be stored there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15611#issuecomment-349231959):

> Enabled/Disabled extensions are not stored in workspace settings. Instead it is stored in local storage cache. You can manage them from the extensions view.

More information on [Managing Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_manage-extensions) can be found in the Visual Studio Code documentation.

If you want to create a shareable list of extensions for specific workspaces (for example, perhaps to commit to source control or sharing with teammates), you can specify a list of [recommended extensions per workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions).

4. Open the command palette
5. Enter **Extensions: Configure Recommended Extensions (Workspace)**
6. Enter a list of extensions IDs

   - For example, you want to recommend the "Visual Studio Code  Ruby" extension

     ```
     "extensions": {
         "recommendations": [
             "wingrunr21.vscode-ruby"
         ]
     }
     ```
   - The format is `{publisherName}.{extensionName}`
   - You can get this from the extension's page in Visual Studio Code
     [image]
7. When the user opens the workspace for the first time, they will be notified of recommended extensions to install.

   [image]

   [image]