# How to install two VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a full-stack developer (PHP + JS).

I want one VS Code for backend and one VS Code for frontend.

I saw a green VS Code in a tutorial but I don't know how to install two VS Code together.

Comment: Why do you need 2? You can open 2 different windows of VS Code, 1 window with the backend workspace, and 1 window for the frontend workspace. Each workspace can have its own extensions (linters, formatters, etc.) and settings.

Comment: I think needing 2 installations is an XY problem. If you just need 2 separate windows or workspaces, see: [How do I open multiple instances of Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29964825/2745495) and [Open multiple Projects/Folders in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30234146/2745495) and [Separate Visual Studio Code workspace with different extensions for different programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61850069/2745495).

Comment: Also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces

Comment: You don't need two versions of VSCode, that is silly... Just open two instances!

Comment: If you are using VS Code for multiple purposes (code editor, log reader, database client, etc.), it's useful to have multiple instances with different profiles (settings, extension, etc.)

Comment: Yes, all try that you can use workspaces, insiders etc.  But, on a Mac, the https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable approach means you can have a dock icon for the dev version.

I use VSCode as my "finder" to see all my files (and view/edit them), so this is ultra-handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your Solution is `workspace`:**

You just need to use VS Code's `workspaces` so you don't need to install two vscodes. just change the `workspace` and that's it. you can install different plugins for different `workspaces`.

***BUT***

If you are curious about the `green icon vscode` that you mentioned, read the rest of my answer.

***Visual Studio Code Insiders***

There is a `beta` version of vscode called `Visual Studio Code Insiders`.

It includes the latest features and bug fixes, but new features may or may not be stable.

It has a green icon.

you can `sign in` with a different account and use it for the front-end and download all the plugins that you need.

you can download it from here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

***Visual Studio Code portable***

The `portable vscode` is also another way to have multiple `vscodes`.

read more info here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable

you can change the `portable vscode icon` color to green pink or what ever you want

Comment: why do you need to use insiders with a different account, it uses a completely different storage for extensions `.vscode-insiders`

Comment: As far as i know, workspaces are mainly presets of folders / root folders of projects you work on. And not separate installations with different plugins & settings.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to install multiple copies of VS Code.**

You just need to use VS Code's ["workspaces"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces):

> A Visual Studio Code "workspace" is the collection of one or more
> folders that are opened in a VS Code window (instance).
> ...
>
> The concept of a workspace enables VS Code to:
>
> - Configure settings that only apply to a specific folder or folders but not others.
> - Persist task and debugger launch configurations that are only valid in the context of that workspace.
> - Store and restore UI state associated with that workspace (for example, the files that are opened).
> - Selectively enable or disable extensions only for that workspace.

If you are coming from other IDEs, a "workspace" is the same as a "project" or a "solution".

You just have to setup 2 workspaces:

- 1 *workspace* for your frontend codes/project
- 1 *workspace* for your backend codes/project

Then just [open 2 windows for each of your workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44000605/2745495):

> Select menu **File** → **New Window** from the menu and then open the other folder in the new window.

[image]

The advantage of this is it allows sharing of extensions, keyboard shortcuts, and other settings between your frontend and your backend workspaces. For example, you have Git-related extensions and settings. With 2 installations, you'll have to track and sync these common settings *every time* something changes. With just 1 installation + workspaces, the settings are shared.

If you're concerned about having different extensions for backend and frontend, see my answer here: [Separate Visual Studio Code workspace with different extensions for different programming languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61850069/2745495). VS Code supports that as well. For example, enable PHP linter extensions only for the backend workspace and JS linter extensions only for the frontend workspace.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68047126/2745495) about using VS Code Insiders *can* work, but the Insiders version is not meant to be used for that. It's mainly used to check/test new features of VS Code before they are released to the stable versions. Some things *may* not be working or missing there (since it's not the "Stable" build).

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of portable instances of VS Code.
Just download it from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable
, then extract and put it in some folder.

For easy accessing, you can create a link of 'Code.exe' inside extracted folder and pin it to the taskbar.

You can also make each one have a different icon color and theme by using instructions from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816831/6339469

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to other questions

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to get two Instances of VS code at the same time.

---

**The First Solution:** use VS code Stable and VS code Insider [I put the link below]

[Insider Vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)

[Vscode & Vscode Insider Together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhUEk.png)

**The Second Solution:** Use the web version of these two versions

[Vscode.dev](https://vscode.dev/)

[insiders.vscode.dev](https://insiders.vscode.dev/)

---

**The Third Solution:** Add a new window by right-clicking on the program icon or via the VSC file menu and the option to add a new window [Below Pics]

[Via File Menu Inside Vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sm0V.png)

[Via Righ Click On Vscode Open And Click On New Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiPAu.png)

---

**The Fourth Solution:** Use the Project Manager extension [Link Below], with the help of which you can add several folders to your VS code and move to your desired project in a few seconds with each click.

[Project Manager Vscode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.project-manager)

[Project Manager Vscode Extension Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3odR.png)

**The Fifth Solution:** You Can Also Use Binaries of VS Code Like VSCodium [Link Below]

[VSCodum](https://vscodium.com/)

---

Comment: this should be the accepted answer considering the question!